# What is the proper way to login a user in ReactJS for a Single-Page Application?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, single-page-application, react-router

Currently, I use ReactJS to make a login page and now I can check the user input and should be able to call a function to AJAX request the server to do something. What is the proper way to login the user and go to the home page of the user? I intend to make a single-page web application.

```
{LOGIN button is chicked} -> {Validate the input pattern} 
-> {Send the username and password to the server} -> {Authenticate the user} 
-> {Load the logined modules} -> {Route to the home page content}
```

Is this a proper way to do a login? If yes, are there some good tutorials to teach me to make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using JWT Authentication. It is easy to use and secure. 
A great tutorial that makes use of the redux architecture is the following:

[Secure Your React and Redux App with JWT Authentication](https://auth0.com/blog/2016/01/04/secure-your-react-and-redux-app-with-jwt-authentication/)

It is also good to practice your react - redux skills.
For the routing of your app I would suggest you to use [React router](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router)
which is straightforward and easy to use.